# calendar jQuery display event from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, events, fullcalendar

How can I display events from a MySQL database in a jQuery fullcalendar?

I would like to display match events from a table in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

Based on details of used framework, etc.. Generally, the logic is:

1. Fetch events from database. You need event date and event name. It is a simple `select` query. Add additional limit conditions, to fetch for period you need.
2. Convert result to javascript `db_events` array.
3. Iterate through array to form necessary literal array:

   ```
   events = [];
   for (i = 0; i < db_array.length; i++) {
     e = db_events[i]; // some calendar event
     events.push(
       {
         title: e[title_id],
         start: new Date(e[start_year_id], e[start_month_id], e[start_day_id]),
         end:   new Date(e[end_year_id], e[end_month_id], e[end_day_id]),
       });
   ```
4. Create jquery calendar:

-

```
<div id='calendar' style='margin:3em 0;font-size:13px'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      events: events
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: i used zend 1.2 and i want to dispaly match in a fullcalendar

Comment: okay. you are familiar with select queries? I think there are no difficult. More important is a schema of your events table (columns, and what they contains)

Comment: print_r( $db->select()->from('events')->limit(1, 0) );

Comment: i use :                                                                      class Match extends Zend_Db_Table {

    protected $_name = 'match';

    public function listMatch() {
        $select = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('a' => $this->_name), array('*'))
                ->order('a.date_match');
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }

}

Comment: and in my view i do :   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },

Comment: is your calendar events stored in 'match' table? what columns? p.s:   you don't specified events array in `fullCalendar` function parameters, you should pass well-formatted array of events there.

Comment: no i just have a table match [id_match,competition,date_match,heure_match] i want to diplay the row  of this table in Fullcalendar

Comment: It seems that you have all necessary details, or -- specify the exact problem there. Cheers